How to properly secure Azure Data Factory Custom Batch Activity command line command?
Imagine running a simple ADF Pipeline that consists of 2 steps:


Fetching a sensitive value - like Storage Account URL - from Azure Key Vault

Executing a Python script with argsparse where this value is set as an argument with the command @{activity('SAURL').output.value


Both Web Activity and Custom Activity have secure input and output values.
THE PROBLEM:
Even though it seems fine from ADF perdpective, when I move to Batch Account -> jobs -> tasks, select Task and move to 'Properties' section, I am able to see the full command line command with the value of my SAURL.
QUESTIONS:

How bad is it from security perspective? The Access to the Batch Account is restricted, but I simply feel bad that I can see these commands.

What is the proper workaround? My current solution is to move the sensitive data to the code and call them with azure.keyvault.secrets library, but it forces me to hard-code the name of the Key-Vault which is also bad. Also it would require adjusting all scripts (from the argsparse versions to the ones calling AKV).

Therefore - is there any option to hash the command line command in the task (from the Batch or ADF perspective)?



Can you provide your activity configurations?
